# How to perform search in drop down list box control in infopath?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I create the List form Template in info path I add on drop down list box in that list box there is thousands of item i want to give search functionality to user user can enter the Name into text box and if this record is exit that tine automatically select into drop down list box.